# How do I apply a border-bottom to each line of a DIV?

Tags: html, css

My code:

```
div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

As the text is long enough word-wrap is taking place. Is it possible to apply a CSS formatted bottom border to the each line of text? Moreover, is it possible to have every bottom border to be at full width of DIV (even if text is only half or less of line width)?

Answer (score 15):

`text-decoration:underline` will work, but if you want more control over the "underline" (colors, styles, width) you can do this:

```
div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    display:inline;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ckt8L/

Comment: This is almost what I want. Is it possible to set inline div's width to 100%?

Comment: You want something that looks like lined paper, with each line's underline 100% width? I don't know of any clean way, but I can think of a few hacky ways to do it, if that's what you're after.

Comment: Exactly! I would appreciate your solution.

Comment: My initial thought is to use a repeating background image of a line, but that's got some problems. I think you'd be better off posting it as a new question at this point. You can reference this one, but be very specific about what you want, what your requirements are, if javascript is ok, what your actual markup is, and if possible provide a screen shot of your desired results. Specify that you're going for the "lined paper" look.

Comment: I think you accepted an answer way too soon, you might have gotten some clever solutions. Besides, isn't a background image what I already suggested? It forces you to use pixel based line-height, plus requires images (harder to style)... but hey if that's all you need, GL!

Answer (score 2):

well for one, wrap the text in `<p>`

then you can apply

`p {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}`

Comment: This applies to whole paragraph, but I need to have bottom border at each line of text.

Answer (score 1):

You could just apply an underline to the text:

```
div {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: @Justin: His example said "1px solid" so I assumed it didn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

A div is a block element, instead of that, use a span that is an inline.

```
<style>
div span{
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
} 
</style>
<div>
   <span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   </span>
</div>
```

See this fiddle with a different approach, using a background as border bottom:

http://jsfiddle.net/YcSUQ/3/

Comment: This is almost what I want. Is it possible to set [tag:span] width to 100% so that border is set to full width of the window?

Comment: It is possible to extend the border to 100% width even if the text is not long enough. But you need to use an image with a dot as background  that will repeat giving you the border effect:
http://jsfiddle.net/YcSUQ/

Comment: This gives border just for one line and if text takes whole line.

Comment: No, the background repeats, try reducing the size of your browser. Anyway, see this new example with more words:
http://jsfiddle.net/YcSUQ/4/